# Erro em função para listar dados de usuário

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tendo o erro abaixo ao listar dados de um usuário pela função `lista()`.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'nome' (T_STRING) in
>   /home/adelanmu/public_html/usuario-class.php on line 54

```
public function lista(){
   $pdo = Conexao::conexao();
   $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_cliente = ' . 
   $_SESSION['id_cliente'];';
   $consulta = $pdo->query($sql);
   $dados = null;
   while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       $dados[] = array(
         "nome" => $linha['nome'],
         "email" => $linha['email'],        
         "senha" => $linha['senha']          
       );     
   }
   $pdo = null;
   return $dados;
}
```

Comment: `$sql  = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_cliente = '".$_SESSION['id_cliente']."'" ;` tenta assim

Comment: Olá Walter tudo bem? Pode postar um dump do array linha? Coloca um var_dump($linha) e posta aqui por favor.

Comment: brother gora aparece esse erro   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id_cliente' in 'where clause'' in /home/adelanmu/public_html/usuario-class.php:55 Stack trace: #0 /home/adelanmu/public_html/usuario-class.php(55): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM u...') #1 /home/adelanmu/public_html/perfil.php(5): Usuario->lista() #2 {main} thrown in /home/adelanmu/public_html/usuario-class.php on line 55